# NodeJs server does not respond under stress test

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, stress-testing

I'm trying to do a stress test(using SOAPUI, screenshot attached with all the test parameters) on a nodejs application hosted on a Windows Azure VM.

As shown in the screenshot, a lot of requests run into errors. I'm using a mongodb server for db interaction and pm2 for keeping the server running indefinitely.

Is there any kind of throttling being done by Azure/Azure VM?  There seems to be error connecting to the db from the node application when this test is done.

Any setting I need to do, or set any parameters?  Any help/pointers will be helpful. Thanks.

[Stress test for the nodejs application, hosted on Windows Azure VM with mongodb at the backend database[Screenshot link]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH3gt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure provides a list of common Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints. You can refer to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/ to know these limits.

In the section `Networking Limits`, There is a limit for concurrent TCP connections for a VM that the default limit is 500K, see the picture below:

[image]

And I searched a third-party performance showdown report for MongoDB vs. SQL Server 2008, please move to http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2010/04/29/mongodb-vs-sql-server-2008-performance-showdown/. The MongoDB has very high performance for read and write operations.

So I don't think your test result for lots of errors was caused by the limits of Azure or interaction with MongoDB.

Per my experience, there might be two cases for your test issue.

1. ISP limits the number of concurrent TCP connections on your test networking. Please enquire the local ISP.
2. NodeJS processing model is single thread model with event loop architecture.  Please review the nodejs code and check the asynchronous logic whether it exists resource competition.

Comment: Yes, there was no throttling being done by Azure itself. It was the application logic that kept on dropping connections. Gotta check the code. Thank you for the links though.